# woocommerce displays incorrect orders in my-orders page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I open my orders page, wooommerce shows random orders thats are not current user orders.
I've disabled all plugins except woocommerce and Then I've acitivatd 2019 wordpress theme.
Then I created this:

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $test_user_id = 7;
    $user_id = $test_user_id;
    echo  $user_id;
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => $user_id,
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

And then I create a page with this shortcode in it:

```
[woocommerce_orders]
```

then I changed `$test_user_id` value to test it.
It shows random orders when I change the id.
Please tell me how can I solve this problem to show current user orders in my orders page.
Thanks

Comment: Could be a caching issue. Not only the caching plugins, but your hosting provider might also have some caching methods.